# How to convert "yyyy-mm-dd" Google Forms field to Date type?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-forms

In Google Apps Script, I try to insert Calendar event after form submit.
On FormSubmit I have the following code:

```
  var startDate = formData.namedValues["From day"];
  var endDate = formData.namedValues["To day"];
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("mycalendarid");

  var startDatecal = new Date(startDate);
  var endDatecal = new Date(endDate);

  Logger.log(startDate); 
  Logger.log(endDate); 
  Logger.log(startDatecal); 
  Logger.log(endDatecal); 

  cal.createEvent(name, startDatecal, endDatecal);
```

The problem is the format of the date in spreadsheet "yyyy-mm-dd" is not recognized by Date() function, here's the log:

```
[15-01-02 12:50:08:752 CET] [2015-01-02]
[15-01-02 12:50:08:753 CET] [2015-01-03] 
[15-01-02 12:50:08:753 CET] Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 GMT+01:00
[15-01-02 12:50:08:754 CET] Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 GMT+01:00 1970
```

My questions are:

- how to properly get the dates from the form in the way it is not dependand on the spreadsheet's locale settings? If it's not possible, how to convert "yyyy-mm-dd" format to something understandable by Date() function?
- how to convert it to Date object then?

Answer (score 0):

startDate and endDate look like an array, use the first element i.e.

```
var startDate = formData.namedValues["From day"][0];
var endDate = formData.namedValues["To day"][0];
```

that way you pass a string in the yyyy-mm-dd format which is what the in-built JS Date object should understand.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, same result:

[15-01-05 10:39:41:644 CET] 2015-01-05
[15-01-05 10:39:41:644 CET] 2015-01-06
[15-01-05 10:39:41:645 CET] Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 GMT+01:00 1970
[15-01-05 10:39:41:645 CET] Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 GMT+01:00 1970